# Why KeyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded() is null?

Tags: android, private-key

```
public KeyPair generateKeyPair(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String alias) {
    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    endDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
    try {
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec spec;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                    .setCertificateNotBefore(startDate.getTime())
                    .setCertificateNotAfter(endDate.getTime())
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                    .build();
        } else {
            spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                    .setAlias(alias)
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=fake"))
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                    .setStartDate(startDate.getTime())
                    .setEndDate(endDate.getTime())
                    .build();
        }
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(spec);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
}
```

i know privateKey.getEncoded can be null, but how to get the privateKey base64 value?

Comment: Were you able to found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using a provider based on a hardware cryptographic device [`AndroidKeyStore`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) it has been set up not to publish private keys outside of it. Therefore, `Key.getEncoded()` on the private key might actually return null. More details [here](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=xZDIAu90ukEC&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=getPrivate().getEncoded()%20return%20null&source=bl&ots=lu-JPNjZp1&sig=ACfU3U0sO1i-BhoyLDXPqh3RiYIu4mDNJg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij6qi-0-XgAhUCiXAKHXL5A2kQ6AEwBXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=getPrivate().getEncoded()%20return%20null&f=false)